# What C++ JSON libraries exist that will work on Windows CE 6.5.3?

Tags: json, parsing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am doing a project that will rely on JSON to communicate with another application. The applications will both run on the same device. It is a Windows CE 6.5.3 device with an ARMv4i processor.

I would prefer it to be a smaller library that does not need additional includes other than its self.

What C++ JSON libraries exist that will work on Windows CE 6.5.3?

Comment: I am beginning to think I am going to have to write my own parser to do this, but I would much rather use an existing one to save time and effort.

Comment: This is a recommendation question and therefore [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) also possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser

Comment: It is a "does this exist" question, and is asking for a much more specific type of json parser than that thread.... though thanks for more stuff to read though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C++ library to read JSON documents into C++ objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538725/is-there-a-c-library-to-read-json-documents-into-c-objects)